# Magento admin not working (too many redirects)

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, url, backend

This morning i changed the System Config Custom Admin URL in magento witch resulted in a 404.
I used this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202950/magento-admin-url-not-working-404-after-changing-it-cant-go-back to revert the change i've made.

I got my www.mystore.com/admin back, but when i log in i get this:

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete.

An the URL looks like this:

```
https://mystore.com/index.php/admin/index/index/key/d27c0da27b776b799fb5f7aa4ebbbda0/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/57c8085a9d1a09359fc39e478c9588e8/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/57c8085a9d1a09359fc39e478c9588e8/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/57c8085a9d1a09359fc39e478c9588e8/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/57c8085a9d1a09359fc39e478c9588e8/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/57c8085a9d1a09359fc39e478c9588e8/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/57c8085a9d1a09359fc39e478c9588e8/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/57c8085a9d1a09359fc39e478c9588e8/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/57c8085a9d1a09359fc39e478c9588e8/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/57c8085a9d1a09359fc39e478c9588e8/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/57c8085a9d1a09359fc39e478c9588e8/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/57c8085a9d1a09359fc39e478c9588e8/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/57c8085a9d1a09359fc39e478c9588e8/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/57c8085a9d1a09359fc39e478c9588e8/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/57c8085a9d1a09359fc39e478c9588e8/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/57c8085a9d1a09359fc39e478c9588e8/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/57c8085a9d1a09359fc39e478c9588e8/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/57c8085a9d1a09359fc39e478c9588e8/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/57c8085a9d1a09359fc39e478c9588e8/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/57c8085a9d1a09359fc39e478c9588e8/?SID=boks2ippnh47oq87dvt910q4n1
```

When i then remove the URL and put in: mystore.com/admin, i get the admin dashboard only in HTML[image: Magento admin dashboard]

My MySQL tables look like this:

```
admin/url/custom = NULL
admin/url/use_custom = 0
admin/url/use_custom_path = 0

web/unsecure/base_url = http://mystore.com/
web/secure/base_url = https://mystore.com/
```

Any fix for this problem?

Comment: Which version of magento please? And does your url contain an underscore? Have you deleted var/cache/

Comment: Magento version 1.9.2.4 and yes i deleted /var/cache and var/sessions

Answer (score 1):

1. It seems like you are using https for secure url so make sure you have installed SSL properly.
2. Also before changing the base secure url,did you checked the media and skin url, is it was a static url there, if yes so you need to change this from core_config_data.

Did you changed admin url from admin panel?

Answer (score -1):

**it is due to Session Validation is set to remote url** 
So, please go to phpmyadmin 
search *Core_config_data*
delete the configration table 
look like

```
Validate REMOTE_ADDR

Validate HTTP_VIA

Validate HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR

Validate HTTP_USER_AGENT
```

i sure it can save your time but sir, do it on your risk thanks @Martvent Developer